# Running linux sftp command in perl doesnt work

Tags: linux, perl, sftp

When I run this in the terminal, it works

```
/usr/bin/sftp -o "IdentityFile=/opt/apps/doc/bin/id_rsa" -b /opt/apps/doc/bin/batch.txt DMS2@convpc1
```

However, when I run this in perl script, nothing happen

```
system("/usr/bin/sftp -o \"IdentityFile=/opt/apps/doc/bin/id_rsa\" -b /opt/apps/doc/bin/batch.txt DMS2@convpc1");
```

I have been spending the entire day trying to figure out how to sftps my file and I cannot figure out the problem?  Any suggestions?

Edit: I did some more testings. I put the entire command in a test.sh file. I ran the test.sh from terminal, it works. I changed the perl file so it is system("/opt/app/doc/bin/test.sh") and then ran it, nothing happen. I added printing statements before the system command, they work, but the system command still doesn't work since I don't see my file being moved.

Comment: Is replacing `system` with `print` one of the ways you tried to figure out the problem?

Comment: You might consider trying [Net::SFTP](http://search.cpan.org/~dbrobins/Net-SFTP-0.10/lib/Net/SFTP.pm) instead of using system. Generally it's more efficient to use native Perl modules instead of escaping out to the system, and in this case the system call is problematic, so it might be worth investigating also to resolve your issue.

Comment: use [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign).

Answer (score 3):

The system command may be eating the quote character, and the '@' character needs escaping as \@.

Try this to see if you are really running the command you are trying to run:

```
my $cmd = "/usr/bin/sftp -o \"IdentityFile=/opt/apps/doc/bin/id_rsa\" -b /opt/apps/doc/bin/batch.txt DMS2@convpc1";

sys($cmd);

sub sys {
    my ($cmd) = @_;
    print "About to run '$cmd'\n";
    (system($cmd) == 0) or die "Unable to run '$cmd' : $!";
}
```

Comment: Since there is no desire to interpolate, it's also possible to single-quote the strings (e.g., `system('/usr/bin/sftp -o "IdentityFile=/opt/apps/doc/bin/id_rsa" -b /opt/apps/doc/bin/batch.txt DMS2@convpc1')`).

Comment: Try running with single quotes, as Max Lybbert suggests above.

Comment: I did some more testings. I put the entire command in a test.sh file. I ran the test.sh from terminal, it works. I changed the perl file so it is system("/opt/app/doc/bin/test.sh") and then ran it, nothing happen. I added printing statements before the system command, they work, but the system command still doesn't work since I don't see my file being moved. Since I put the command in sh, quote shouldn't matter anymore

Comment: Add some echo statements inside your test.sh and see if they get run.

Comment: cat foo.sh

       `#!/bin/sh
       echo "hello world"`
perl -e 'system("foo.sh");'
`hello world`

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
    $result = "/usr/bin/sftp -o \"IdentityFile=/opt/apps/doc/bin/id_rsa\" -b /opt/apps/doc/bin/batch.txt DMS2\@convpc1";
    system($result);
```

Are you getting any syntax errors? Try "perl -cw scriptname" and see the result.

I would suggest **Net::SFTP** which is very convenient for establishing SFTP connection.

Comment: Using a variable instead of a literal shouldn't make a difference.  But using Net::SFTP  is the best suggestion.  Upvoted.

Comment: @MaxLybbert: Net::SFTP is an old, unmaintained and buggy module, and it relies on Net::SSH::Perl that can be quite difficult to install (and that is also old, unmaintained and buggy). Not the best suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the information about Net::SFTP.  So while the advice in particular is bad, I stand by the comment that the general idea (use a module instead of calling `system`) is still the best approach.